# XFCE4 keyboard switcher not switching

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, keyboard-layout, xfce4

I have three keyboard layouts configured in my new XFCE4 desktop. I added the keyboard-switcher add-on to the toolbar, but it only ever shows the default (American) layout... Clicking on it -- left or middle mouse-button -- has no effect.

If I right-click, a menu pops up with keyboard-configuration among options. If I choose that, I get the XFCE4's keyboard config interface, which just shows the three already configured layouts...

(The keyboard shortcut, that I selected for layout switching -- right Win-key -- has no effect either, but I never use it anyway.)

How do I debug this any further? Thanks!

EDIT: after an unrelated restart, the switcher is switching now... Of course, it should not be necessary...

Answer (score -1):

A restart fixed it... Maybe, we shouldn't be mocking Microsoft so hard for needing a reboot on every sneeze... :(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/670873)

Comment: It _does_ tell anyone faced with the same problem, how to work around it. As far as "leaving a comment" below "an author's post" -- which author and which comment should I have targeted to avoid your self-righteous -1?